# Convert each list element to string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file with headers. I used Pandas to read and converted it to json using to_json function.
`test = df.to_json(orient = 'records')`
The output I have is 
`[{"Name":"xyz", "Age":10},{"Name":"fyk", "Age":10}]` The final output I want is a list with each element as a string:
`['{"Name":"xyz", "Age":10}','{"Name":"fyk", "Age":10}']`. Any help on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
>>> import json
>>> test = df.to_json(orient = 'records')
>>> map(json.dumps, test)
['{"Age": 10, "Name": "xyz"}', '{"Age": 10, "Name": "fyk"}']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it gives me a weird output if I convert it to a list. It applies dumps to each element i.e.it is split Age as A g e separately. Can you suggest how I can print it using a print.